# macOS Catalina how to upgrade the Apache httpd

Tags: catalina, apache

I have upgraded my laptop from Mojave to Catalina.

I do not use my laptop with any of the Apache Services.

My current version of Apache httpd is: Apache/2.4.41

My security team told me that I need to update to Apache/2.4.42 or later.

Again, I am not using the Apache Server, I am not trying to update any path and at the same time I can not install Brew on my mac.

I simply need to update this Apache httpd version that come by default in my MacOS.

How do I do that? Can I run a simple command line that update the Apache httpd version to 2.4.42 or later.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't upgrade the system version. If you don't use Apache at all just disable it (command is in the linked question). It then won't show up on any network scans your security team is doing.

Comment: @nohillside thanks....that means in order for me to update the Apache httpd version my only hope is that Apple release a native macOS Catalina Security Update that will eventually include the updated version of the Apache httpd to a newer version?

Comment: Which is higly unlikely. May be better to reach out to the security team to understand their concerns, and the options you have to resolve this.

Comment: @nohillside thanks i will disable httpd Apache and at the same time I will let them know that if they want me to update Apache httpd (without using third party software like brew or nmap or etc.) or we update to Big Sur which I do believe it contain a newer version of Apache httpd (2.4.46) or we just wait somehow Apple will release a Catalina Security Update that will update Apache httpd